Localstorage is not defined Angular
I'm building this project and got stuck with localStorage. I'm trying to save the count state when add button is clicked. So  that when I refresh the page, the number is still there.
--- cart.service.ts---
key= "count";


private Count = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.getlocal());
Count$ = this.Count.asObservable();

incrementCount(){
   const newCont = this.Count.value+1;
   this.Count.next(newCont);
   this.setlocal(newCont);
 }


 getlocal(): number {
  const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(this.key); 
  return storedValue !== null ? parseInt(storedValue, 10) : 0;
}

setlocal(count: number) {
  localStorage.setItem(this.key, count.toString());
}

Then I have an app component with the incrementcount function. And a navcomponent that receive the count through html.
Error ng0100 ..help me fix this pls!

When using SSR, and you want to use browser APIs, you need to wrap this code in afterRender or afterNextRender, otherwise this code may be executed on server side (Node.JS), where localStorage does not exist. Also you cannot directly return the value from local storage in a function, you will need to adjust the logic to load the value from the storage.
private Count = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

constructor(private readonly environmentInjector: EnvironmentInjector) {
  afterNextRender(() => {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(this.key);
    const count = storedValue !== null ? parseInt(storedValue, 10) : 0;
    this.Count.next(count);
  });
}

setlocal(count: number) {
  runInInjectionContext(this.environmentInjector, () =>
    afterNextRender(() => localStorage.setItem(this.key, count.toString()))
  );
}


Property 'value' does not exist on type 'ReplaySubject

@NOne changed back to BehaviorSubject, now it should work

Error: NG0203: afterNextRender() can only be used within an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with runInInjectionContext.

@NOne updated my answer

I'm getting error ng0100 , can you help me with that?

@NOne NG0100 cannot have anything to do with the code from my answer

Please replace the below code in cart.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {
  private readonly key = 'count';

  // Initialize the count to 0 for each new session
  private Count = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  Count$ = this.Count.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    // Reset count in localStorage to 0 on service initialization
    this.setLocal(0);
  }

  incrementCount() {
    const newCount = this.Count.value + 1;
    this.Count.next(newCount);
    this.setLocal(newCount);
  }


  private setLocal(count: number) {
    if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
      localStorage.setItem(this.key, count.toString());
    }
  }
}


This just silences the error, but when using SSR the value is not stored. Also you just removed the logic to load the value from local storage. This is not what was asked for.
